# How to not lose edit focus on textbox implement a virtual keyboard with Korean IME

Tags: c#, virtual-keyboard

I'm trying to make a virtual keyboard with C# in my project
and I found Korean keyboard doesn't work well.

The Keyboard consists with buttons as keyboard keys and user clicks the buttons to type.
Key linked the function utilizing user32.

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern void keybd_event(byte vk, byte scan, int flags, int extra);
```

The problem is, if user click 'ㄱ' and user click 'ㅏ' to add vowel, it doesn't continue writing not '가' it types as 'ㄱㅏ' separated two characters.

I figured out there are two modes of selection

1. select

[image: 2]

2. edit mode(Not sure how to call)

[image: 1]

Please help me to know

1. Not to lose the curser editmode state
2. What is the editmode called
3. When I lose editmode, how can i get editmode back using event, property..  anyway